# Concatenation bits in value

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to concatenate bits, such as:

```
0x10 plus 0x12 = 0x1012
or
0x123 plus 0x4 = 0x1234
```

How I can do it, without string classes?

Comment: I have mistake with term, I had mean "concatenation".

Comment: What should happen for e.g. `0x1234` "plus" `0x0` ? Should this be `0x12340` ? `0x1234` ?

Comment: @PaulR And what should happen for e.g. `0x1234` "plus" `0x0000`? :) I guess, that `0x0` means no addition. Else, it has to be defined clearly, how many digits should be shifted in such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to evaluate the rank of the rightmost value.

I believe, something like this should work:

```
// Returns rank of the value increased by one (except, when value == 0)
int rank(int value)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (value > 0)
    {
        value /= 16;
        result++;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int left = 0x12;
    int right = 0x34;

    int sum = (left << (4 * rank(right))) + right;

    printf("%x\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: pay attention to operator precedence in expressions like a << b + c

Comment: Close. It should be `sum = (left << (4 * rank)) + right;` - watch out for operator precedence.

Comment: Is it ok to assume _4_ always? I dunno, I'm just asking here to see if it'll work across platforms. I guess endianness doesn't matter since C's operators guarantee you that.

Comment: Yes. To shift a hexadecimal number one place to the left, you have to shift exactly 4 bits (2^4 = 16).

Comment: @Spook Oh got it, irrespective of the platform, the number of bits to hold a hex digit is 4.

Comment: @Spook: Why name it rank? Won't `digits` be more appropriate? Googling for rank doesn't give me an explanation, please explain.

Comment: The rank of a digit is its position in a value. For example, units has rank 0, tens - 1, hundreds - 2, etc. Checking the rank of a value means checking, what is the rank of its mostly-significant position.

Comment: @Spook: But for 0x1 rank is 1 and not 0; shouldn't the ranking start at 1? i.e. units 1, tens 2, etc?

Comment: @legends2k No, because rank equals to power to which you must raise the base to reach given position. The rank of 5 in 25 is 0, because 5 = 5 * 10^0. The rank of 2 in 25 is 1, because 20 = 2 * 10^1. Also, the ranks are continuous - the rank of 3 in 0.3 is equal to -1. Notice, that I return ranks increased by one from my function for the purpose of this particular problem. But that doesn't change their definition.

Comment: @Spook: Aah, now I get it! Thanks for patiently explaining :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is finding the position of the first hexadecimal digit in the second number, shift the first number to the left accordingly and then sum the numbers. To efficiently find the first digit of a binary number see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set
Then make a modulo 4 operation to find the first hexadecimal digit.

Comment: +1: idea's sound, but "shift the first number to the right accordingly" should be left, and "make a modulo 8" should be modulo 4 as there are 4 bits in a hex digit, and like Spook your algo just works as stated for positive numbers.